# Formula to randomly select the name associated with lowest value from data set & a random from the lowest options if tied with drop-down select filter

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a data set on Google Sheets where for example,

| Name | Scores | Region | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Row | Row | Row |
| Second | Row | Row | Row |

On another tab, I have a drop-down list to select a specific Region and State. I am looking for a formula that apply these drop-down filters and select the name associated with the lowest score and if there are multiple names that are tied, randomly select from those names.

Ex Scenario 1 - The formula should randomly select Adam when the drop-downs selected are East and New York.

| Name | Scores | Region | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 2 | East | New York |
| Bill | 3 | West | California |
| Charlie | 4 | East | New York |
| David | 4 | West | Seattle |
| Steve | 2 | West | California |

Ex Scenario 2 - The formula should select a random name from Adam and Charlie when the drop-downs selected are East and New York.

| Name | Scores | Region | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 2 | East | New York |
| Bill | 3 | West | California |
| Charlie | 2 | East | New York |
| David | 2 | West | Seattle |
| Steve | 2 | West | California |

Ex Scenario 3 - The formula should select a random name from Bill and Steve when the drop-downs selected are West and California

| Name | Scores | Region | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 4 | East | New York |
| Bill | 2 | West | California |
| Charlie | 2 | East | New York |
| David | 5 | West | Seattle |
| Steve | 2 | West | California |

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168942/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Comment: Removed leading spaces from your table markup so that the data gets shown as tables. If the answer below does not solve your problem, please comment below the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sortn()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  area, city, 
  lambda( 
    names, scores, 
    sortn(names, 1, 0, scores, true, randarray(rows(scores)), true) 
  )( 
    filter(Data!A2:A, Data!C2:C = area, Data!D2:D = city), 
    filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C = area, Data!D2:D = city) 
  ) 
)( 
  "East", "New York" 
)
```

Replace `"East"` and `"New York"` with references to the pertinent drop-down list cells, and `Data` with the name of your data sheet.

Comment: Thank you doubleunary! This works. Very much appreciated.